Postfix TLS library problem: error:14094418 when sending emails from a PHP app using sendgrid-mailer
I have a legacy PHP app running on Apache 2.4.37 on Rocky Linux 8. This uses sendgrid-mailer to post emails. This is configured as follows:
MAILER_DSN=smtp://127.0.0.1:25
I have Postfix running on the same host. When attempting to send an email from the PHP app, the following error is logged and no email is posted.
Aug 21 15:47:41 MyLAMPServer postfix/smtpd[2215547]: warning: TLS library problem: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 48:

My understanding is that the SSL verification between my PHP app (client) and Postfix is failing - it's attempting to verify 127.0.0.1 (localhost).
Postfix configuration (postconf -n) that's different from default is:
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = $myhostname
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

Any thoughts on how to fix it or bypass the verification?

If you google "SSL alert number 48" you'll find that this is an "Unknown CA" error, meaning that your CA certificates are either outdated or broken. Updating the ca-certificates package may fix the former.

Thanks for the pointer. I hadn't realised what the number 48 meant.

I'm not sure this is the safest approach but since my PHP site and Postfix are on the same host, I decided to convert the self-signed certificate from PEM to CRT format, add it to the CA Trust directory and update the CA trust store.
openssl x509 -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/postfix.pem -out ~/downloads/postfix.crt
cp ~/downloads/postfix.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/.
update-ca-trust

I am no longer seeing the error.
